# cant log in to the database file on visual studio asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

net and SQL server so i am trying to do the code first approach after i created the models for the database and enable and add migrations on the packet manager when i update-database command in the packet manager it works fine but when i want to see the database in the server explorer i get the following error :

```
The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following information:
Login failed for user 'LAPTOP-U9AV480S\NS'.
```

and this is my web.config file with the connection string value

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server = LAPTOP-U9AV480S\SQLEXPRESS2 ;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-vidly.mdf; integrated security = true"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

the SQL server is EXPRESS and i configured the security and the login to window authentication

please help me I am stuck in this for two days

Comment: The error suggests the local user account 'NS' have you tried connecting in SQL Server Management Studio or similar software?

Comment: @RyanThomas yes i tried on the management studio it works fine only from the visual studio i cant